# A Single Letter is missing from each, can you figure it out to find the answer and the question?

Tags: lateral-thinking, letter-sequence

Grasshopper, in order to know the answer you must first figure out the question.

```
H, H, D, P, ?                     (2)
P, L, T, Q, P, H, H, ?            (5)
R, C, C, U, B, A, ?               (9)
A, K, Q, J, T, N, E, ?           (11)
M, V, E, M, J, S, ?              (14)
D, P, N, G, C, M, ?              (15)
M, K, S, P, S, ?                 (16)
Y, C, A, G, ?                    (18)
A, T, G, C, L, V, ?              (48)
Z, O, T, T, F, F, S, S, E, N, ? (112)  
H, H, L, B, B, C, ?             (613)
A, A, N, S, A, ?             (371017)
```

Hint 1:

> The answer is 3 letters long

Hint 2 (Bounty Hint):

```
H, H, D, P, ?, Z.                     (2)  
M, K, S, PH, S, ?, DP, DD, DQ...     (16)
```

Also anyone who has a better title LMK

Comment: Something simple like "Discover the missing letters" would probably suffice. is there supposed to be a letter missing from the fourth line? - looks like you already fixed that. :)

Comment: @BaileyM  It isn't just about discovering the letters, the numbers are also involved

Comment: Is the question made from discovering the missing letters?

Comment: Grasshopper, eh?

Comment: @qwertylpc Well, you've inspired another puzzle from me: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18363/a-quindectet-of-letter-sequences

Comment: As a side note, based on the Grasshopper reference, I was really hoping the answer would be "wax". =P

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Alright, I'm going to start a partial answer, we'll see if it goes anywhere.

Missing letters:

Edit: Thanks to [minitech](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/1565/minitech) for number 6! Thanks to [Len](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5188/len) for number 1! Thanks to [Geobits](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/1563/geobits) for number 7!

> 1. H (Hestia, Hades, Demeter, Poseidon, **Hera**) - Cronus and Rhea's Children
> 2. O (Point, Line, Triangle, ..., Heptagon, **Octagon**) - Polygon by number of sides
> 3. I (Russia, Canada, China, United States, Brazil, Australia, **India**) - Countries by Area
> 4. S (Ace, King, Queen, Jack, ..., Eight, **Seven**) - Cards
> 5. U (Mercury, Venus, Earth, ..., Saturn,  **Uranus**) - Planets
> 6. M (Delaware, Pennsylvania, New Jersey, ..., Massachusetts, **Maryland**) - US States by Ratification Date
> 7. B (McDonalds, KFC, Subway, Pizza Hut, Starbucks, **Burger King**) - Largest Fast Food Chains in the World by number of stores
> 8. R (Yankees, Cardinals, Athletics, Giants, **Red Sox**) - Most World Series titles
> 9. L (Aries, Taurus, Gemini, Cancer, Leo, Virgo, **Libra**) - Signs of the zodiac
> 10. T (Zero, One, Two, Three, ..., Nine, **Ten**)  - Counting to ten
> 11. N (Hydrogen, Helium, Lithium, ..., Carbon, **Nitrogen**) - Periodic Table Elements
> 12. E (Asia, Africa, North America, South America, Antarctica, **Europe**) - Continents by Area

Cleaning up the list and adding the numbers gives us:

> `H      2`
> `O      5`
> `I      9`
> `S     11`
> `U     14`
> `M     15`
> `B     16`
> `R     18`
> `L     48`
> `T    112`
> `N    613`
> `E 371017`

EDIT: From [Deusovi's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi) answer below

"Deciphered the numbers based off VictorHenry's answer! All I had to do was...
add a couple suggestive spaces:"

> `H         2`
> `O         5`
> `I         9`
> `S        11`
> `U        14`
> `M        15`
> `B        16`
> `R        18`
> `L       4 8`
> `T      1 12`
> `N      6 13`
> `E 3 7 10 17`
>  Each set of numbers tells us where that letter is located in the final phrase:
>  `1 2 3   4 5 6 7 8 9101112  131415161718`
>  `T H E   L O N E L I E S T   N U M B E R`
>  So the final answer is **ONE!**

Comment: All correct thus far.  I have a new puzzle for you since you seem to be reading my mind today http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18350/an-hourglass-puzzle

Comment: [Maryland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_by_date_of_admission_to_the_Union)

Comment: Everything so far is correct

Comment: Perhaps ["Cronus sired six children by Rhea: Hestia, Hades, Demeter, Poseidon, Hera, and Zeus in that order"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhea_(mythology)#Myths_and_genealogy)

Comment: @Len That is correct

Comment: #7 is `B` or `BK`, at least according to [this list](http://www.forbes.com/pictures/mlf45ejhgi/top-10-global-fast-food-brands-3/). I see them in different orders on a couple other sites, but they may be measuring differently. I only add the `BK` option because the hint has some with double letters, but I assume it's just `B`.

Comment: I don't know what the numbers are, but the letters anagram to `OH NUMBER LIST`, or something along those lines.

Comment: Can I ask why #4 is S? Shouldn't it be N?

Comment: @CaelanO'Toole The full list in the OP is `A, K, Q, J, T, N, E, ?`. He cut some out and ellipsized them to save room in the answer.

Comment: OP? What is the OP? And I still don't see why #4 isn't N.

Comment: @CaelanO'Toole OP is Original Post (the question itself). It's S for Seven because the list goes from Ace down to Eight and the next after that is Seven.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Silly me, since I just read the ... as the one you need to fill in.

Comment: @Geobits it could also be `HI LOST NUMBER`

Answer (score 15):

Deciphered the numbers based off VictorHenry's answer! All I had to do was...

> add a couple suggestive spaces:
>  H [2]
>  O [5]
>  I [9]
>  S [11]
>  U [14]
>  M [15]
>  B [16]
>  R [18]
>  L [4 8]
>  T [1 12]
>  N [6 13]
>  E [3 7 10 17]
>  Each set of numbers tells us where that letter is located in the final phrase. It spells out THE LONELIEST NUMBER, so the final answer is ONE!

Comment: Nicely done! I was going nowhere with those numbers, but I knew someone would solve it!

Comment: @VictorHenry and Deusovi Seeing as you both contributed a lot, I am not sure I know how to best award the bounty and the correct answer.  I have posted about it on Puzzling Meta here: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3209/dealing-with-partial-answers-and-a-bounty,  if either of you guys have ideas please let me know

Comment: @qwertylpc Well in this particular case, several of my answers were crowdsourced, and I feel like Deusovi made the major leap, at least as far as the "lateral thinking" part of the puzzle went. Makes sense to me to give it to Deusovi.

Comment: @VictorHenry, you got most of it though. I didn't do nearly as much as you did.

Comment: How about one of you gets the bounty, the other gets the check mark?

Comment: @qwertylpc: I don't really care, tbh - resolve it however you see fit.

Comment: @qwertylpc what Deusovi said :D

Comment: @qwertylpc Accept this one as it is THE answer, bounty to VictorHenry and then give a couple of Deusovi's accepted answers some +1 love? :)

Comment: I edited VictorHenry's answer to be complete, and will mark that as the best answer while awading the bounty to Deusovi because he/she finished it after I posted the bounty

Comment: @JamieBarker You do know that [serial upvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me/126857#126857) is not allowed on SE and can get you into trouble?

Comment: @mmking surely you can only be a _serial_ upvoter if you do more than 2, considering you have to kill three or more people to be classed as a [_serial killer_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_killer). I only suggested a couple of upvotes ;)

Comment: @JamieBarker You mean 2 or more people? No. It is considered serial upvoting if you go around and upvote *one* person several times in a short period of time. And by "a couple of upvotes", I'm assuming you mean more than one or two. Do read the meta post I linked to.

Comment: @mmking Yes I read the post, and I agree it is serial up-voting if you go and up-vote one person _several_ times in a short time period. This is **different**. Going through someone's posts and "_systematically upvoting them_" is far different to finding one or two (a couple means two, not more than, not less than, **two**) to vote-up that _deserve_ an up-vote, such as _most_ accepted answers.