# A Quindectet of Letter Sequences!

Tags: english, knowledge, letter-sequence

I've been working hard on trying to solve the missing letters in [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18344/a-single-letter-is-missing-from-each-can-you-figure-it-out-to-find-the-answer-a) by qwertylpc, but I've discovered that in trying to figure out the lists his clues are coming from, I've come up with several lists of my own! Since I am stumped on the last two clues in his puzzle, I'm going to dump all of the clues I've thought of into this puzzle!

**EASY**
1) P, N, D, ?
2) P, K, B, R, ?
3) F, C, G, D, ?
4) B, K, M, G, ?

**MEDIUM**
5) B, G, B, G, R, ?
6) G, E, L, N, D, J, J, ?
7) T, T, C, P, Q, ?
8) H, O, T, T, S, F, ?
9) W, J, L, H, J, G, ?

**HARD**
10) E, F, W, W, ?
11) L, G, G, S, W, E, ?
12) P, T, F, C, G, G, ?
13) M, J, P, L, S, D, H, ?
14) S, C, P, G, O, ?

**VERY HARD**
15) L, H, H, B, S, B, B, ?

Important information:

- Note the [english](/questions/tagged/english) tag. Also, many of these are US-centric, including one that would have a slightly different sequence in Britain.
- All of the letters come from **ordered lists of things**. So you don't have to worry about how the letters look (e.g. A, E, F, H, I, ? is "K" because no curved lines in the capital letters), or their position in the alphabet (no need to do math or anything).
- All of the answers are the **first** letter of a word, but **not necessarily** from the first word in a phrase/name. So if the sequence is Neil Armstrong, Buzz Aldrin, Pete Conrad, I wouldn't give you "E, U, E" or "G, N, D" but I could just as easily give you "A, A, C" as "N, B, P".
- Difficulty groupings are based on my best guess. I suspect some will be easier than I thought, and possibly some will be harder than I thought, but I thought I'd at least make an attempt to classify them.

I would like to avoid giving ANY hints on this puzzle if possible, but I guess we'll see how it goes, particularly with the last one. I'm already thinking of other sequences, so maybe I'll make a sequel!

**Edit: Bounty added!** In addition to the regular bounty, I'll give another 50 points to whoever solves the VERY HARD sequence (#15), so even if you can only solve that one, go ahead and make your own answer!

Comment: And 2. is probably either N or Q, but I can't figure out why they're in that order.

Comment: @JoeZ. Yes, P, N, D is correct. I think I know what your problem is with 2; it might help you to know that N is not actually a letter in that sequence.

Comment: I know what one of them is, but can't be bothered to write up an answer for just one. So I'll give a simple (but non-obvious) hint: number 9 has to do with faces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**COPIED OVER FROM JOE Z'S ANSWER (#1 to #6)**

> **1.** Q. This is the order of the value of U.S. coins (Penny, Nickel, Dime). The next one is **Quarter**.
>
> **2.** Q. This the order of the value ranks of chess pieces (Pawn, Knight, Bishop, Rook). The next one is **Queen**.
>
> **3.** A. This is the order of sharps in Western key signature notation (F, C, G, D, A, E, B). It's also the initials of the mnemonic "Father Charles Goes Down **And** Ends Battle".
>
> **4.** T. This is the order of SI prefixes being applied to bytes (Bytes, Kilobytes, Megabytes, Gigabytes). The next one is **Terabytes**.
>
> **5.** J. This is the order of the *first* names of United States Presidents from Obama going backwards (Barack, George, Bill, George, Ronald). The next one is **Jimmy** Carter.
>
> **6.** R. This is the order of the books of the Old Testament in the Bible (Genesis, Exodus, Leviticus, Numbers, Deuteronomy, Joshua, Judges). The next one is **Ruth**.

**ANSWERS FROM OTHERS (#7, #9, #14)**

> **7.** G. Teaspoon, Tablespoon, Cup, Pint, Quart, **Gallon**. (From Bailey M.)
>
> **9.** F. Faces on US paper currency: Washington, Jefferson, Lincoln, Hamilton, Jackson, Grant, **Franklin**. (From dennisdeems)
>
> **14.** H. The Harry Potter series: **S**orcerer's Stone, **C**hamber of Secrets, **P**risoner of Azkaban, **G**oblet of Fire, **O**rder of the Phoenix, **H**alf-Blood Prince
> (outside of the US, the first name is Philosopher's Stone)
> (From GordonK)

**LEN'S ANSWERS**

8) H, O, T, T, S, F, ?

> Poker hand ranking:
> **H**igh card, **O**ne pair, **T**wo pair, **T**hree of a kind, **S**traight, **F**lush, **F**ull house **. . .**

10) E, F, W, W, ?

> The five powers in Captain Planet and the Planeteers (animated TV series):
> **E**arth, **F**ire, **W**ind, **W**ater, **H**eart

11) L, G, G, S, W, E, ?

> The seven deadly sins, in the order used by Pope Gregory I:
> **L**ust, **G**luttony, **G**reed, **S**loth, **W**rath, **E**nvy, **P**ride

12) P, T, F, C, G, G, ?

> "The Twelve Days of Christmas" song:
>  a **P**artridge, two **T**urtle doves, three **F**rench hens, four **C**alling birds, five **G**old rings, six **G**eese a-laying, seven **S**wans a-swimming **. . .**

13) M, J, P, L, S, D, H, ?

> US state capitals ordered by the alphabetical state names:
> **M**ontgomery Alabama, **J**uneau Alaska, **P**hoenix Arizona, **L**ittle Rock Arkansas, **S**acramento California, **D**enver Colorado, **H**artford Connecticut, **D**over Delaware **. . .**

15) L, H, H, B, S, B, B, ?

> The twelve labours of Hercules:
> Nemean **L**ion, Lernaean **H**ydra, Ceryneian **H**ind, Erymanthian **B**oar, Augean **S**tables, Stymphalian **B**irds, Cretan **B**ull, **M**ares of Diomedes **. . .**

Comment: 8 is correct, 10 is close but not correct. (The answer is much less respectable than Chinese philosophy =P )

Comment: All of these are now correct.

Comment: I edited your post to include everybody's answers. I'm giving the 50 point bounty to Joe Z. and giving you a 100 point bounty. I have to wait 24 hours to award it to you, though, so you'll get it tomorrow. Really well done, especially on 15!

Comment: @VictorHenry - Thanks very much :-)

Answer (score 6):

Some answers that I've gotten so far:

> **1.** Q. This is the order of the value of U.S. coins (Penny, Nickel, Dime). The next one is **Quarter**.
>
> **2.** Q. This the order of the value ranks of chess pieces (Pawn, Knight, Bishop, Rook). The next one is **Queen**.
>
> **3.** A. This is the order of sharps in Western key signature notation (F, C, G, D, A, E, B). It's also the initials of the mnemonic "Father Charles Goes Down **And** Ends Battle".
>
> **4.** T. This is the order of SI prefixes being applied to bytes (Bytes, Kilobytes, Megabytes, Gigabytes). The next one is **Terabytes**.
>
> **5.** J. This is the order of the *first* names of United States Presidents from Obama going backwards (Barack, George, Bill, George, Ronald). The next one is **Jimmy** Carter.
>
> **6.** R. This is the order of the books of the Old Testament in the Bible (Genesis, Exodus, Leviticus, Numbers, Deuteronomy, Joshua, Judges). The next one is **Ruth**.

Comment: I cannot for the life of me figure out how to format this for spoilers. It just adds an exclamation point! Anyway, you're correct on all of these so far.

Comment: It's because of the hard enter spacing. You have to use `<p>` in order for spoiler tags to work.

Comment: 7 I believe is G: Teaspoon, Tablespoon, Cup, Pint, Quart, Gallon.

Comment: 14 should be H - Harry Potter and ... Sorceror's Stone, Chamber of Secrets, Prisoner of Az, Goblet if Fire, Order of Phoenix, Half-Blood Prince

Comment: Yep, you're both correct.

Comment: Everything in the answer and comments is correct.

Answer (score 5):

9) W, J, L, H, J, G, ?

> The people pictured on US currency:
>  1 dollar: **W**ashington
>  2 dollar: **J**efferson
>  5 dollar: **L**incoln
>  10 dollar: **H**amilton
>  20 dollar: **J**ackson
>  50 dollar: **G**rant
>  100 dollar: **F**ranklin
>
> Thanks to GlenO for the hint

Comment: This is correct.

Answer (score 2):

> 7) T, T, C, P, Q, ?

> Teaspoon, Tablespoon, Cup, Pint, Quart, Gallon

Edit:

I did come up with this on my own, and posted before I saw @Bailey M.s comment.